# How to pass a function as parameter in xargs?

Tags: bash

I have this example:

```
migrate(){
    case $1 in 
        "team_container")
            echo "Rodando Migrate de ${1}",

            ;;
        "evaluation_container")
            echo "Rodando Migrate de ${1}",

            ;;
        "school_container")
            echo "Rodando Migrate de ${1}",

            ;;
        "class_container")
            echo "Rodando Migrate de ${1}",

            ;;
        "student_container")
            echo "Rodando Migrate de ${1}",

            ;;
        "messages_container")
            echo "Rodando Migrate de ${1}",

            ;;
        "logs_container")
            echo "Rodando Migrate de ${1}",

            ;;
    esac
}
export MIGRATE=migrate;
docker ps  --format {{.Names}} | xargs bash -c "MIGRATE {}"
```

Output:

> MIGRATE: command not found

xargs cannot find the function, even if exporting it and calling a subshell.

How can i pass my function migrate as parameter to xargs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as argument:

```
xargs -n1 bash -c 'migrate "$1"' _
```

Remember to export your function:

```
export -f migrate
```